# How is this not a function in coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Seems relatively straight forward :

```
_.each words, (val, key) -> $(".word_choice")[key].html val
```

Returns :

```
$(".word_choice")[key].html is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

return $(".word_choice")[key].html(val);
```

Can't figure this out. I'm using this reference :

http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/literate/underscore.html#each

Comment: Ah me too! I thought it was well honest question, phrased well with a good reference? Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When accessing an element by index in a jQuery object, you get back a plain HTML element, not another jQuery object. Use [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) instead:

```
_.each words, (val, key) -> $(".word_choice").eq(key).html val
```